# Official/Advised/Allowable maximum number of records (or RAM Table Size) in ETS / Mnesia RAM Table

Tags: windows, linux, unix, erlang, mnesia

Erlang has been a good application to many "New Age" (obscenely fast and fault tolerant ) Messaging Systems. Examples can be [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com), [ejabberd](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/), [WhatsApp for Mobile](http://blog.whatsapp.com/index.php/2011/09/one-million/) e.t.c. Regardless of how a messaging system is built, it will need to know what sessions are going on, who is logged on, e.t.c. I assume that holding data `IN-MEMORY` is unavoidable for such systems. 
For Erlang, what is the possible maximum, OR what is the allowed maximum OR what is the officially advised maximum number of records in an `ETS table` or `mnesia RAM table` ?  Is there a certain Table size that is known to crash the whole VM if exceeded ? Do `ETS Tables` or `Mnesia RAM Tables` grow to any amount as long as the underlying Operating System allows it ?  I have heard of `Mnesia Table Limit` of `2 or 4GB`, but i thought that this is for Disk tables.
 A Typical example of future applications that will need to process large amounts of data IN-MEMORY are `OLAP Systems`, `Real Time analytics`, `Social Gaming` e.t.c. Thinking in this line has motivated this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mnesia is a wrapping layer of ETS and DETS tables. For a 32bit system a maximum value of a ETS table is about 3.5GB. For a 64bit system maximum value is much more, so technically it is limited by RAM available for OS. For DETS (and it is very stupid) limit is 2GB.

I don't have any benchmarks with other key-value storage systems, but remember, that ETS stores Erlang terms directly without any encoding/decoding.

Comment: But how to limit the size, If for example I'm using it for cache?